# In the MCU, who created the technology surrounding the Infinity Stones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

In the MCU, each of the Infinity Stones encountered so far has been "wrapped" in a technology that seems to tap into one or more abilities of the stone, or dampen them. But who exactly created the technology each of the stones powers?

- The **Space** stone is the core of the **Tesseract**. Was this built by the Asgardians, or did they simply use it as they found it to build the Bifrost?
- The **Reality** stone is the core of the **Aether**. Was this built by Malekith, or did he simply find it in that form and realize it could be used to his ends?
- The **Mind** stone is the core of the **Scepter**. Was this built by Thanos, or did someone else make it?
- The **Power** stone was found in a protective **Orb**, not in an active weapon. Did the Moragians encase it, or someone else?
- The **Time** stone is the core of the **Eye of Agamotto**. Was this built by Agamotto, or did he simply find the relic in that state and was the first to figure out how to use it?
- The **Soul** stone was only accessible on the planet Vormir after the seeker sacrifices someone close to them. Who or what set up this test?

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we see a vision from Thor showing the first four stones bursting out of their respective encasing in their regular stone form. So the question really is, who or what made the technologies of each stone as encountered in the MCU?

I'm looking for *canon* answers, ideally either in-universe spoken or narrated by someone/something that can be counted as factual (IE not just a guess or a part of a civilization's lore that hasn't been verified), or out-of-universe from one of the producers/directors.

Comment: I believe that in Thor: The Dark World, Odin says that Malekith created the aether.

Answer (score 5):

Since the utilization of the Infinity Stones were notoriously prominent among Celestials, it's clearly hypothetical the Celestials most apparently created the containment units for three Infinity Stones: Space Stone, Mind Stone and Reality Stone.

The Orb casing was not built by Moragians; the casing was built by surviving cosmic beings after failing to harness its greatest power. They hid the orb in the abandoned, uninhabited planet Morag.

The Eye of Agamotto was built by the first sorcerer supreme, Agamotto himself.

- The Tesseract was not built by the Asgardians; however, the Tesseract fell into the hands of the Asgardians who then harnessed its power to build the interstellar portal bridge accessing the Nine Realms and beyond. It is highly likely that the Celestials created the cube-shaped crystalline containment vessel for the Space Stone in order to open portals from realm to realm as on their journey to seek life in the Universe within.
- The Scepter was not built by Thanos. The Scepter isn't of Chitauri Origin; undoubtedly, the Scepter could be of either Kree or Celestial Origins. The jewel casing for the Mind Stone remains a mystery; whether the jewel casing is a possible extract of the Terrigen Crystal or other crystal elements.
- The Aether was not forged by the Dark Elf Malekith; rather, the Dark Elves probably "discovered" the Aether then attempted to harness its power to unleash darkness. The Celestials possibly liquefied the Reality Stone into Aether to host and manipulate reality.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for these claims? Are they from the comic books? This question was asking specifically about the MCU of which Ego is the only celestial we've witnessed.

Comment: There is an unnamed Celestial shown wielding the Power Stone atop a long staff in the holograph projection that The Collector shows the Guardians in GotGv1.

Comment: While these are logical guesses, we need supporting evidence before I can upvote or accept.

Comment: In agents of sheild (which is technically cannon) lady Sif claims (speaking to Phil Coulson) that  "Thor saw you stabbed through the heart with a Chitauri sceptre", which suggests Thor (or at least lady Sif) believed Thanos created the Sceptre. This makes a lot of sense, given that when thanos had the mind stone he would have probably removed it from it's housing to study it even if it was originally in sceptre.